# How to add additional fonts to the Windows console windows

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe, regedit

I was recently doing a search on Bing and read that it is possible to have more fonts than appear on the screen.
This really interested me and I tried it and could not do it.

- I am on windows 8.1
- I Use the following location:

  ```
  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
  ```
- I have successfully deleted a font, but can't get a font.
- I am using fonts that Windows has preinstalled
- I am using string values (REG_SZ)
- I am using the numbers: 00,000,0000,00000,000000, and fowar

What can I do to get the fonts?


 [The article I read](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/)

Comment: The problem is to get Unicode and UTF-8 glyphs to show properly, when used is various console programs. For a full solution look [here](https://superuser.com/a/1381619/116221).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increment the string by adding a 0 to every one.

So the standard Lucida Console is `0`. The first custom font is `00`, the second custom font is `000`.

Note very few fonts are usable.

Consolas is one font you can add. Plus at work in PuTTY there are 4 TTFs that are fixed width so there are two more other than Consolas you can use.

From [KB247815](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/247815):

> Necessary Criteria for Fonts to Be Available in a Command Window
>
> Q247815
>
> ---
>
> The information in this article applies to:
>
> Microsoft Windows 2000 Server
>      Microsoft Windows 2000 Advanced Server
>      Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional Edition
>      Microsoft Windows 2000 Datacenter Server
>      Microsoft Windows NT Server 4.0 Standard Edition
>      Microsoft Windows NT Workstation 4.0 Developer Edition
>
> ---
>
> SUMMARY
>
> For fonts to be available for use in a command session (Cmd.exe)
>   window (on the Fonts tab in the CMD Properties dialog box), the fonts
>   must meet certain criteria.
>
> The fonts must meet the following criteria to be available in a
>   command session window:
>
> - The font must be a fixed-pitch font.
> - The font cannot be an italic font.
> - The font cannot have a negative A or C space.
> - If it is a TrueType font, it must be FF_MODERN.
> - If it is not a TrueType font, it must be OEM_CHARSET.
>
> Additional criteria for Asian installations:
>
> - If it is not a TrueType font, the face name must be "Terminal."
> - If it is an Asian TrueType font, it must also be an Asian character set.
>
> In Windows 2000, the installation of Console Fonts is no longer
>   automated. This was done to give the console window greater stability
>   in multilanguage environments. An unsupported work around is available
>   by adding the following font specific entry:
>
> ```
> Add a String Value
> Name=00
> Data= "Font Name" (without "")
> ```
>
> Into the following registry:
>
> ```
> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
> ```
>
> The name needs to be incremented with "0" for each additional font.
>   The Data entry needs to match the font's entry in the following
>   registry location:
>
> ```
> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
> ```

Comment: What font works? Can you give an example?

Comment: in win 7 , this font works:  https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/ , and it includes all utf8 characters , in windows by default there is also `Courier New` font.
after installing the `deja vu` font I added `DejaVu Sans Mono` in the registry , now I can chose it from the console settings